# Reducing signal noise arduino to simulink analog read

Tags: arduino, noise

I'm using an op amp to amplify the input of a pressure sensor from milli volt to volts using with arduino. Both the amp and the sensor are externally powered using a DC power supply.
I'm trying to read this analog signal off the arduino using Matlab Simulink, But I am getting a lot of noise while trying to read. I'm not sure what is causing the error, any suggestions?

I would need to read the voltage value so that I can make a lookup table from it ( relating corresponding voltage values to pressure values)

Comment: please add a schematic, the sensor datasheet, and what is this noise.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the amount of noise generated by the MCU itself by telling it to enter ADC Noise Reduction sleep mode. This will turn off the CPU, I/O, and synchronous timers (which will disrupt `delay()` et alia) while still allowing the ADC and other critical functions to run. A no-op ADC interrupt will allow the device to wake from sleep once the conversion has completed.

See the "Power Management" section, "ADC Noise Reduction Mode" subsection and the "Analog-to-Digital Converter" section, "ADC Noise Canceler" subsection of the MCU used in your specific Arduino for more details.